# How to Add Custom Favicon In Blogger through html?

Tags: blogger, favicon

I am using a third-party template in Blogger and favicon option not showing in Layout. I have used this code but not working ]]></b:skin>

Comment: You can now change the favicon from settings: Settings > Basic > Favicon

Answer (score 0):

access settings in the panel, then Favicon and Select a favicon file. Use a square image that is less than 100 KB.

[image]

and in the html define the

```
 <link href='https: //myblog.blogspot.com/favicon.ico' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon' />
```